# How to view models in Forge Viewer in combination with 3-legged authentication when view was created with 2 legged client credentials authentication

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've uploaded a model to the model derivative service using the 2-legged authentication workflow with client credentials (backend process)

Now, I am trying to view this model in Forge Viewer after using the 3-legged authentication workflow. When the token of this connection is parsed to the viewer I am unable to view the model (frontend process)

Both authentication workflows are using the same client credentials.

Does anybody know why this is failing? Should it be possible to use the workflow above to view models?

Comment: What was the error message? 401 unauthorized or ...? Did you use the same client ID for the translation jobs? Technically it's possible to view the models with 3 legged tokens - see [these](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) endpoints support user context as optional flow

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bryan. Yes the error was 401. Good to hear it would be technically possible. We’ll dive into it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested and turns out for derivatives extracted from models uploaded to your own buckets then the Derivative Service endpoints that Viewer is calling to obtain the necessary model data is two legged only and hence would not accept 3 legged tokens.

You will need to obtain a 2 legged token for derivatives extracted from models in your own buckets and I will let Engineering know it'd be good to support 3 legged tokens for the DS endpoints as well and come back to update this answer when the support is there.

However if we are talking about B360 then the picture changes - let me know if that's the case.